# Where does Windows Server 2012 R2 Expect to see the WindowsImageBackup folder?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, backup-restoration, windows-server-backup

Whenever I try to recover a server from the Windows Reccovery Environment, it never finds the backup image.  I tried the networking option, but it never sees it.  It scans the share, no error, finds nothing.

If I do it "normal," no network share, then it does not find it, and I cannot change where it is looking.  It is grayed out:

[image]

Where does Windows 2012 R2 expect to see the WindowsImageBackup folder at?  And, can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't care as long as the path includes WindowsImageBackup. When we were attempting a restore we created an ISO and the name of the CD was WindowsImageBackup - we re-burned it with the folder WindowsImageBackup as the root and it showed up in the wizard.

I've done this via CD, mounted ISO, and UNC.